# How can I find each instance of a string inside two other strings (Tags)

Tags: php, html, xml, string

The code I'm using searches for a string inside two other strings (tags). The string it searches through is a list of ID's. The ID's are listed in between tags. My code can successfully pull and list one ID, but is there a way to loop it and have it pull them all and assign them to variables or an array?

Here is the code:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){

$string = " ". $string;

$ini = strpos($string,$start);

if ($ini == 0) return "";

$ini += strlen($start);

$len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;

return substr($string, $ini, $len);

}


$resumeid = get_string_between($xml, "<ResumeID>", "</ResumeID>");

echo $resumeid;
```

I tried using the foreach() function, but it didn't seem to work:

```
foreach( $resumeid as $item )
{
    echo $item.'<br />';
}
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You might want to look at PHP's XML manipulation features for this job rather than string manipulation.

Comment: if you're pulling the text node from a DOM element, why not use a DOM parser?  It would be much more robust than regexes.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies. @Gordon I have tried to use some of the XML manipulation features, such as simpleXML, but it never seemed to work. The string is just a bunch of tags without the XML encoding.

Comment: @dnagirl I am not very familiar with DOM parsers. I check those out and see what I can come up with. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop the function not just the results of the function alternatively just use regular expressions rather than a complicated series of string functions will be much easier.

```
preg_match_all("/(<ResumeID>)(\w+)(<\/ResumeID>)/", $xml, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $match)
{
    echo $match."<br />";
}
```

Comment: I assumed there was a reason you weren't using something like SimpleXML http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: That did exactly what I needed it to. Thank you! I did look at using SimpleXML, but I do need to do a little more than it allows.